# My nested view is only changing the url but not linking to the templateurl

Tags: node.js, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;

}]);


app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/app/components/home/home.html',
            controller:'HomeController',
            controllerAs:'homeCtrl'
        })
    .state('home.csharp', {
        url: '/csharp',
        templateUrl: '/app/components/home/csharp.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        },
        controllerAs: ''
        })
```

I'm not able to link my template url of `home.csharp.`. But still the url changes in the url bar but view doesn't change.

Comment: Do you have `ng-view` in you main html page?